# Avoid expose connection string in startup WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have WPF project and class library is handling EF 6.0 with Database first approach. Now i want entity classes into my startup project(WPF project) without adding connection string in startup project app.config. I google out class EntityConnectionStringbuilder that will help to generate dynamically connection string. But, I can't find solution with database first approach and entityconnectionstringbuilder.

Please help me to eloborate EntityConnectionStringbuilder example in Db first approach or suggest me different approach.

Comment: use `EntityConnectionStringbuilder.ToString()` to get connection string

Comment: if i write using(var dbenties = new DB_Entities()) so where to pass connection string and DB_Entites constructor is auto generated as I have DB first approach

Comment: I got solution with DB first approach by creating partial class on my dll project and parameterized constructor as connection string.

  I created partial class with same namespace.
    public partial class SampleEntities : DbContext
    {

     public SampleEntities(string connectionstring): base(connectionstring)
     {
     }
     }

And everything is same as earlier before. Now i am accessing this class.
While calling, I used EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Connectionstring in new object.

       using(SampleEntities obj = new SampleEntities(connectionstring))
       { }

Answer (score 0):

You can use code first approach

Create a sample class first

```
public class Sample
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a task context for the task

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext(string connection) : base(connection)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TaskContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a connection string

```
 string ConnectionString = string.Format("data source=.;initial catalog={0}; User Id={1};Password={2};", connection.FileName, connection.UserName, connection.Password);
```

Now pass the connection string to SampleContext it will create database for you

```
 SampleContext = new SampleContext(ConnectionString);
```

change the connection string based on your usage

Comment: I got solution with DB first approach by creating partial class on my dll project and parameterized constructor as connection string.

  I created partial class with same namespace.
    public partial class SampleEntities : DbContext
    {

     public SampleEntities(string connectionstring): base(connectionstring)
     {
     }
     }

And everything is same as earlier before. Now i am accessing this class.
While calling, I used EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Connectionstring in new object.

       using(SampleEntities obj = new SampleEntities(connectionstring))
       { }